Firebase apple push notifications code signing: automatic or manual?
We have a react native expo application built and released to testflight (and play console) by an Azure Devops pipeline. We want to add the capability to receive firebase push notifications.
If we configure xcodebuild like this:
    CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic \
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" \
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE="" \

then the app builds and releases correctly, but we get a warning from the appstore:

ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement

If, however we configure the pipeline like this:
    CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual \
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)" \
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE="$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)" \

then it fails with numerous build errors (an error for each framework file used):

error: React-perflogger does not support provisioning profiles. React-perflogger does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Edge fund provisioning profile - App Connect has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'React-perflogger' from project 'Pods').

Our understanding is that the error is due to xcode trying to sign library files.
What's our way out of this? Should CODE_SIGN_STYLE be Automatic or Manual, and if Automatic, how to make sure we don't get the warning from the appstore?
